# Unable to write list of elements to a file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of elements and I want to write below elements to file using print() function using python.

Python gui: version 3.3

Sample code:

```
D = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
flog_out = open("Logfile.txt","w+") 
for key in sorted(D):
    print(key , '=>', D[key],flog_out)
flog_out.close()
```

Output when I run in IDLE gui:

```
a => 1 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Logfile.txt' mode='w+' encoding='cp1252'>
b => 2 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Logfile.txt' mode='w+' encoding='cp1252'>
c => 3 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Logfile.txt' mode='w+' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I don't see any line written in the output file. I tried using the flog_out.write(), it looks we can pass one argument in write() function. Can anybody look into my code and tell if I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you please add your expected output to your question?

Answer (score 6):

If you are specifying a file-like object to [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), you need to use a [*named* kwarg](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) (`file=<descriptor>`) syntax.  All unnamed positional arguments to `print` will be concatenated together with a space.

i.e.

```
print(key , '=>', D[key], file=flog_out)
```

works.

Answer (score 2):

From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print)

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

All of your arguments, `key`, `'=>'`, `D[key]`, and `flog_out`, are packed into `*objects` and printed to stdout. You need to add a keyword argument for `flog_out` like so:

```
print(key , '=>', D[key], file=flog_out)
```

in order to prevent it from treating it like *just-another-object*

Answer (score 0):

```
D = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
flog_out = open("Logfile.txt","w+") 
for key in sorted(D):
    flog_out.write("{} => {}".format(key,D[key]))
flog_out.close()
```

Though if I were writing it I'd use a context manager and `dict.items()`

```
D = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
with open("Logfile.txt","w+") as flog_out:
    for key,value in sorted(D.items()):
        flog_out.write("{} => {}".format(key,value))
```