# Prints on stdout but unable to write to file in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm really frustrated with this strange behaviour of Python all of a sudden. I've been writing to files all sorts of data but since today morning it just doesn't seem to work. I've referred to all these before posting:

- [How to redirect 'print' output to a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python)
- [Failed to write to file but generates no Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017958/failed-to-write-to-file-but-generates-no-error)
- [Unable to write data into a file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780099/unable-to-write-data-into-a-file-using-python)
- [Unable to write list of elements to a file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342192/unable-to-write-list-of-elements-to-a-file-using-python)

Have tried all following commands but it just doesn't write anything to the delete.txt file. What's happening?

```
fl=open('delete.txt','w')
fl.write(msg) <--Doesnt work,tried this also
fl.write('%s' %msg) <--Doesnt work,tried this also
fl.write("at least write this") <-- Doesnt work,tried this also
print (msg) <- WORKS
```

Code:

```
for i in hd_com.comment_message[1:500]:
fl=open('delete.txt','wb')

try:
    if len(i)>40:
        mes=processComUni(i)
        proc=nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(mes)
        #print proc
        pos=nltk.pos_tag(proc)
        for i in pos:
            if ((i[1]=="NN") or (i[1]=="NNP") or (i[1]=="NNS")) and len(i[0])>2:
                #print i[0],i[1]
                for j in home_depo_inv:
                    if i[0] in j.split() and (i[0]!='depot' and i[0]!='home' and i[0]!='store' and i[0]!='por' and i[0]!='get' and i[0]!='house' and i[0]!='find' and i[0]!='part' and i[0]!='son' and i[0]!='put' and i[0]!='lot' and i[0]!='christmas' and i[0]!='post'):
                        a=re.findall(i[0],j)
                        fl.write(str(i))<--Doesnt work,tried this also
                        fl.write(str(mes))<--Doesnt work,tried this also
                        fl.write("\n")<--Doesnt work,tried this also
                        fl.write("hello")<--Doesnt work,tried this also
                        fl.flush()
                        break
except:
    continue
fl.close()
```

More code:

```
type(mes) = str
mes="omg would love front yard"
```

Comment: Do you get an error? How do these not work?

Comment: no errors on console. Why is it that prints working fine, but its not writing the same to a file ?

Comment: whats the type of `msg` ? try `type(msg)`

Comment: Try `print(msg,file=fl)`

Comment: type(msg)=str, os=win8, editor=ipython. This strange error for the first time since working on python

Comment: @kdopen SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: is your file in a same directory with your code ?

Comment: What Python version? Did you close the file before attempting to verify its contents?

Comment: @Kasra yes all in same directories. Python version = 2.7

Comment: Refresh the page, I already solved your issue in an answer below =)

Comment: did you try with another file ? create another file and try with ! and give us the result !

Comment: @Kasra checked again ,now its writing only the last message (mes) to the file. Not writing the previous lines. I guess they are getting overwritten or something

Comment: so good , how you write `msg` to file ? and whats it look like ?

Comment: Pls see my code that Ive added in question. Thats how im writing mes to file

Comment: Change the `except:` to `except Exception as exp:` and then print the except out (rather than ignoring it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snippet's indentation is totally messed up, but anyway: your code starts with:

```
for i in hd_com.comment_message[1:500]:
    fl=open('delete.txt','wb')
```

which means you reopen the file for writing on each iteration, erasing whatever might have been written by the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the output stream explicitly when writing to a file handle like that.

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write("this is a test\n")
# no text in the output file at this point
f.flush()
# buffers are flushed to the file
f.write("this, too, is a test\n")
# again, line doesn't show in the file
f.close()
# closing the file flushes the buffers, text appears in file
```

From the documentation of file.write:

> Note that due to buffering, flush() or close() may be needed before the file on disk reflects the data written.

Comment: Doesnt work either, have updated my code with your suggestions in question, still no luck

Comment: its writing only the last message (mes) to the file. Not writing the previous lines. I guess they are getting overwritten or something. Whats even happening here.